# Replace deprecated gets()

Tags: c, getline, buffer-overflow, gets

I am using the SLM toolkit by CMU-Cambridge for some baseline language modeling on language data, but when I run one of the built executables, my system detects a buffer overflow when it tries to execute one of the commands.

Based on [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172409/buffer-overflow-detected-in-a-program-that-runs-flawlessly-apparently) I noticed that `__gets_chk+0x179` caused the problem, and I've found two occurrences of `gets/fgets` in the source code (evallm.c, also available [in this GitHub project someone made](https://github.com/quinnj/WinCMUToolkit/blob/master/src/evallm.c)) but I do not know how to fix them in a proper/secure way.

The relevant parts of the error message:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /home/CMU-Cam_Toolkit_v2/bin/evallm terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__gets_chk+0x179)[0x7f613bc719e9]
Aborted
```

The `broken code`

```
# declaration of input string variable
char input_string[500];

# occurence 1
...
while (fgets (wlist_entry, sizeof (wlist_entry),context_cues_fp)) { ... } 
...

# occurence 2
...
while (!feof(stdin) && !told_to_quit) {
    printf("evallm : ");
    gets(input_string);
....
```

The error basically occurred when the *input_string* I gave to the `evallm` command was too long. Normally it is to be called from the command line and you can interactively pass arguments. However, I piped all arguments together with the command (as seen in the example of the docs) but apparently sometimes my argument names where taking too much bytes. When I changed the array length of *input_string* from 500 to 2000 the problem was solved (so I guess the error was due to occurence 2). But I really would like to fix it by replacing `gets()` by `getline()` since it seems to be the right way to go. Or is replacing it by `fgets()` also a solution? If so, what parameters should I use?

However, when trying to replace `gets()`, I always get compiling errors. I'm not a C-programmer (Python, Java) and I'm not familiar with the syntax of `getline()`, so I'm struggling to find the right parameters.

Comment: You can also use fgets, the only difference for gets is that it has length.

Comment: Unrelated to your `gets`/`fgets` problem, but you might be interested in reading [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the heads up! The code has been around for quite a while (1999) so I can imagine some deprecated or 'olde timey' programming concepts are still present. I'll look into it!

Comment: There is a clear distinction between "old time programming concepts" (you mean "style, btw) and "problematic"/unsafe code. One can write very well safe code in assembly language.

Comment: And see [ask] and provide a [mcve]. You missed vital information.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not saying the C-language is bad, but that this code is probably written in a style which has more modern alternatives since it hasn't been updated since 1999. I haven't read the `while ( !feof (file))` article yet so I don't know whether it's an issue of erroneous code or unclear/bad style.

Comment: @Olaf, also; what's the issue with my code example? The fact that it's incomplete and not reproducible? Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @mbauwens: Please follow the links I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case, you know that `input_string`  is an array of 500 bytes. (Of course, you could replace that 500 with e.g. 2048)

I am paranoid, adept of defensive programming, and I would zero that buffer before any input, e.g.

```
memset(input_string, 0, sizeof(input_string));
```

<sup>So the buffer is cleared, even when `fgets` has failed. In most cases that is in principle useless. But you have corner cases and the evil is in the details.</sup>

So read documentation of [fgets(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) and replace the `gets` call with

```
fgets(input_string, sizeof(input_string), stdin);
```

<sup>(you actually should handle corner cases, e.g. failure of `fgets` and input line longer than `input_string` ....)</sup>

Of course, you may want to zero the terminating newline. For that, add

```
int input_len = strlen(input_string);
if (input_len>0) input_string[input_len-1] = '\0`;
```

<sup>(as commented, you might clear the `input_string` less often, e.g. at start and on `fgets` failure)</sup>

Notice that [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) is POSIX specific and is managing a heap-allocated buffer. Read about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). If you are unfamiliar with C programming, that might be tricky to you. BTW, you could even consider using the Linux specific [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html)

<sup>The main point is your familiarity with C programming.</sup>

NB: in C, `#` does not start a comment, but a [preprocessor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor) directive.

Comment: The easier way is to just zero out the first entry **iff** `fgets` fails. `memset` for each call can be a significant performance issue.

Comment: On the other hand, if it is human-typed input, you practically don't care. You would care if stdin was redirected (e.g. in a pipeline)

Comment: Alwas be prepared. It does not look like it takes console input only. It would not cause much more effort, just checking the result, which you have to anyway.

Comment: If code uses `fgets(input_string, sizeof(input_string), stdin); int input_len = strlen(input_string); ... ` instead of `gets(input_string);`, also suggest `char input_string[500];` --> `char input_string[500+1];` to consistently handle valid extreme test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You replace `gets` with `fgets`.

It's *almost* that simple, the difference (besides the arguments) is that with `fgets` there might be a newline at the end of the buffer. (Note I say it *might* be there.)

I recommend [this `fgets` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Comment: ...and you use the presence / absence of that newline to check if you've gotten the whole line, or ran into the size limit.

Comment: OP specifically mentioned `getline`, which in my opinion is safer than `fgets`. When recommending `fgets`, this answer implicitly recommends against `getline`. Is this intended? If yes, you must explain why.

Comment: When I looked up the buffer overflow issues with `gets`, the most common answer was to replace it with `getline`. Other than that I have no real preference for the one or the other. Just a safe alternative which keeps the script from aborting.

Comment: @anatolyg I recommend `fgets` because it's a standard C function. The `getline` function is a POSIX function and is not available anywhere. But otherwise I agree, `getline` might be a better choice if portability is not an issue.

Comment: @anatolyg `getline()` has a feature that at first looks good: auto allocating a buffer to the size of input.  Yet with various nefarious users attempting to break code, this trades the buffer overrun problem of `gets()` with allowing the (evil) user to overwhelm memory resources with a _long_ line. Employing a generous sane upper bound on user input length is reasonable.  Unfortunately I see no C  stand-alone function yet as well handling that.